# How to get admin config values from a specific store view

Tags: magento2

Currently, I'm getting my values like:

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('settings/basics/language', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

But this, of course, gets me the default value.

How do I get the config value of a certain store view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you look into `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in `getValue()` method

This method accept the 3 parameter

- `$path` The path through the tree of configuration values e.g., `'general/store_information/name'`
- string `$scopeType` The scope to use to determine config value, e.g., `'store'` or `'default'`
- null|string `$scopeCode`

So If you want to get store config by store wise then you just need to pass `second` (so you can define you want value as `storewise` or `website`) as well as third parameter (you can pass your `store code` here).

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

protected $scopeConfig;


public function __construct(
    ...
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ....
}
```

Now you can get store config value by

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('your/path/config',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,'store_code');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value from specific store by passing third parameter which is store code define in `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` class.

```
public function getValue($path, $scopeType = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeCode = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
            $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;
    $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("section_id/group_id/field_id", $storeScope);
```

> section_id, group_id, field_id values you can find in
>   etc/adminhtml/system.xml path in your custom / (default vendor) Module