# How to get admin config values in the root folder

Tags: magento2

I need to get admin values to a PHP file located in Magento 2 root folder.

In Magento 1 I could do it by:

```
require ('./../../app/Mage.php');
```

How can I do this in Magento 2?

Comment: What do you mean by admin values? You want to access magento code in custom script ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant admin config values. Or calling a helper for that matter. But yes I want to access magento code in custom script

Comment: You mean store config values ?

Comment: I know how to get the values I need, the problem is that the magento code is not recognized in the root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$config = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
echo $config->getValue('path/to/config', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
exit;
```

You just need to replace `path/to/config` with your config path

Comment: $review should be $config ;)

Comment: but it works great, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is typo updated the answer :) @JurģisTomsLiepiņš

Comment: Sorry, do you know how to get the value from a certain storeview with this method?

Comment: I added the answer into your question please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209552/2589 @JurģisTomsLiepiņš