# How to implement a method retrieving config value both at store and default scope: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, helper, core-config-data, magento2-3

In Magento 1, a call to `Mage::getStoreConfig('section/group/field')` was able to retrieve a config of the current store. Indeed, if we called it from a front block for example, it retrieved the config value of the current store and if we called it from an admin block, it retrieved the value of the admin store (`id=0`).

Is it still possible in Magento 2 to have such a method ?

For example, I created an helper with the following content :

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Config extends AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_FEATURE_ENABLED = 'section/group/my_feature_enabled';

    /**
     * Get enabled config
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function isEnabled($storeId = null)
    {     
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_FEATURE_ENABLED,
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $storeId
            );
    }
}
```

For informations : in my test environnement, I have only one store view.
My `core_config_data` table looks like :

```
scope   |  scope_id |                path               |    value 
default |    0      | section/group/my_feature_enabled  |      0
stores  |    1      | section/group/my_feature_enabled  |      1
```

When I call it from the frontend area, it works as expected (returns `1`). But when I call it from the admin, it does not return the default admin value : it returns `1` too ...

If I change `ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE` by `default` in the `isEnabled` method, it always returns the default value (admin value) but it's not returning the good front end value anymore ...

So, what is the Magento 2 way to have the same result as the Magento 1 `Mage::getStoreConfig` method ?

**UPDATE :**

Using the answer of @Sumit, I was able to create a method working as I expected :

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Config extends AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_FEATURE_ENABLED = 'section/group/my_feature_enabled';

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    protected $_state;
    /**
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isEnabled;

    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_state = $state;
    }
    /**
     * Get enabled config
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function isEnabled($storeId = null)
    {     
       $scopeCode = ($this->_state->getAreaCode() == Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) ?
                    ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT :
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
       return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_FEATURE_ENABLED,
                $scopeCode,
                $storeId
              );

    }
}
```

If there is other suggestion, please share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with below code.

```
protected $_scopeConfig;
protected $_areaCode;

public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $areaCode
) 
{
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_areaCode = $areaCode;
}

public function getYourValue() {
    if($this->_areaCode->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
         //if area is admin
    } else {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;
        $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("section_id/group_id/field_id", $storeScope);
    }
}
```

> Reference: [How to get admin config values from a specific store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209527/how-to-get-admin-config-values-from-a-specific-store-view?rq=1)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried and the result is the same : it returns a correct value for front call but incorrect in admin.

Comment: I think this is default Magento feature to get the value from the store view if it is different from the default view. If you want both of the values in your code for default and store view, then you can pass the store on conditional basis in your helper as per your requirement.

Comment: I've updated my code as per your requirement, please have a review.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I will try it asap. I agree with your sentence : `I think this is default Magento feature to get the value from the store view if it is different from the default view.`  and that's the problem I'm pointing out : when I am from the admin, retrieving a value with a store scope should return the default config : because the admin store is the default store (in my Magento 1 way of thinking). The current result (with my code) is not the expected result. Now I will try your updated code !

Comment: your logic is working. I will upvote your answer (I will flag it as the accepted answer later if there is no other acceptable proposition). I will edit my question too with an updated code using your answer's logic.