# How get default ReCaptcha key programmatically on Frontend?

Tags: magento2, frontend, recaptcha

[image]

I want to used this key in my Custom Module so how to get this this key using block.

I create a form on frontend which has a Recaptcha V2. How to used default keys for this Form.

And I also need to check is enable for Frontend (Backend) or not.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_ReCaptcha/blob/master/Model/Config.php

Comment: have you fetched the value using this concept https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209527/how-to-get-admin-config-values-from-a-specific-store-view  That value will stored in the path https://prnt.sc/pze6tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the below code in your block and let me know.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;    
class TestClassName extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    const XML_PATH_ENABLED_FRONTEND = 'msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled';
    const XML_PATH_PUBLIC_KEY       = 'msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/general/public_key';


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig       
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getFrontendCaptchaEnabled()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_ENABLED_FRONTEND,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

    public function getSecurityCaptchaKey()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_PUBLIC_KEY,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

if you would like to call the above method in your template file use this syntax

> $block->getSecurityCaptchaKey();